# Highchart in long array group categories

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

i use bar chart in highchart if my array became more than 15 then it merge them and not show the category in x of

```
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
plotOptions: {

    series: {
    startFromThreshold: false,
        threshold: null,
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.y:.1f}'
        }
    },
    bar: {
        cropThreshold:1,
        turboThreshold:10000

    }

},
```

[jsfid](https://jsfiddle.net/aliysefian/hzragvko/31/)
how can i change the threshold of merging my array items ?

Answer (score 1):

The category labels are hidden ("grouped") because the x-axis is too crowded with labels. You can use `xAxis.tickPositioner` to override the default `tickInterval`, as `tickInterval` may remove ticks if it is too crowded to properly display the labels. You then need to implement the `tickPositioner` to return all the tick positions you want. In your case, all of them.

For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzragvko/51/)), in ES6:

```
tickPositioner: function() {
    return [...Array(this.max - this.min).keys()];
}
```

Or if you don't want to do ES6:

```
tickPositioner: function() {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(this.max - this.min)).map(function (_, i) {return i;});
}
```

Where `this` is the x-axis, and `min` and `max` are are the are used to find the range of the axis.